# Trying to get a Third Monitor to work on Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I’ve built a new computer and I’m considering trying to use Kubuntu on it. I have three monitors connected to the HDMI, DVI and VGA ports. Unfortunately when I start up, the display configuration is completely messed up. e.g. The VGA is connected to a 1080p display. However when I start up, it has some weird much smaller resolution. When I look at `System Settings → Display and Monitor` it shows my VGA (DP-2) can be only set up to 1024x768.

I’m not familiar with Linux, but I’m trying to find out if I can fix this. At the moment I can sort of fix this by adding the mode to `xrandr`.

```
/usr/bin/xrandr --output eDP-1 --off  
/usr/bin/xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
/usr/bin/xrandr --addmode DP-2 1920x1080
/usr/bin/xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x30 --output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1680x0 --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3600x0
```

I don’t think this is ideal and I would like to know how to fix this. 
In this regard I would like to know:

**1. Is KDE and X the same? If they are different which starts first? Can I do this manually, so I an find out where the problem is? Right now I just get to the login screen**

**2. For my situation which log files do I need to check to diagnose this issue?**

My configuration by `kinfocenter` is:

- Kubuntu version: 16.10
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.7.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.26.0
- Qt Version: 5.6.1
- Kernel Version: 4.8.0-46-generic OS
- Type: 64-bit

For Hardware I’m using:

- ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING LGA 1151 Intel Z170 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard
- Intel Core i7-6700K 8M Skylake Quad-Core 4.0 GHz LGA 1151 91W BX80662I76700K Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 530

Please let me know if I have left out any details that are needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is KDE and X the same? If they are different which starts first?

They are not the same, X starts first.

This Thursday a new Kubuntu version will be released, with improvements in multi-monitor management.

If I were you, I would try your setup with the new version.

Comment: Thank you. While I look forward to, I would like to know how to debug this.